# Xamarin Forms Activity Indicator not showing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, activity-indicator

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application. I want to show an ActivityIndicator while getting data & binding it to a ListView control from web API. In my code, ActivityIndicator doesn't show at all. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin 4.10.

Following is my code.

**Code Behind**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    private SfListView listView;
    private ActivityIndicator activityIndicator;

    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StackLayout mainStackLayout = new StackLayout();

        activityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator()
        {
            IsRunning = true,
            IsEnabled = true,
            IsVisible = true
        };
        listView = new SfListView()
        {
            SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };

        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(activityIndicator);
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(listView);

        this.Content = mainStackLayout;
        this.Title = "Dashboard";
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        SummaryRepository viewModel = new SummaryRepository();

        listView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Summary;
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var grid = new Grid();

            var bookName = new Label
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                FontSize = 16,
                TextColor = Color.FromHex("#1A237E")
            };
            var bookDescription = new Label
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                FontSize = 16,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
                TextColor = Color.FromHex("#EC407A")
            };

            bookName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            bookDescription.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Amount"));

            grid.Children.Add(bookName);
            grid.Children.Add(bookDescription, 1, 0);

            return grid;
        });

        activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

**XAML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="eWallet.Pages.TestPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#F5F5F5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
               //Your Listview
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Padding="12" x:Name="DisplayLoading" IsVisible="False"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">
                <ActivityIndicator Color="#d7813e" IsRunning="True"/>
                <Label Text="Loading..." TextColor="#d7813e" FontSize="Small"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>       
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

And in cs file use :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        SummaryRepository viewModel = new SummaryRepository();

        listView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Summary;
        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var grid = new Grid();

            var bookName = new Label
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                FontSize = 16,
                TextColor = Color.FromHex("#1A237E")
            };
            var bookDescription = new Label
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                FontSize = 16,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End,
                TextColor = Color.FromHex("#EC407A")
            };

            bookName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            bookDescription.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Amount"));

            grid.Children.Add(bookName);
            grid.Children.Add(bookDescription, 1, 0);

            return grid;
        });

        activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `OnAppearing` method is fetching the data and binding into the listview source synchronously, which means that when the view is created, the data is already binded and the `activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;` disappears the indicator. So you dont actually see it running. Because when the view is shown the binding is already completed and indicator is `false`.

One suggestion is that..

Listview already has `IsRefreshing` property, set this to `true` and you will see the indicator running, `false` to disappear.

You can also use `IsPullToRefreshEnabled` to `true` so the user can actually pull down the listview to show the indicator running and invoke refresh command so you can do refresh method here.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what is happening is exactly what Luminous said. You are calling `activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;` on `OnAppearing()` method, so, if the fetch goes to fast, you're not going to see the activity indicator. Try to use a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` to check if that's the case.